# Why this conditon variable is not working?

Tags: c++, multithreading

I was trying to understand the `condition_variable` available in C++ standard. So in the below test code I have written, I expect the `func1` to be woken up after printing 50 numbers in main thread but here it prints all numbers only from main thread?

Could you please help me here to understand `condition_variable` better to indicate a certain thread to wake up

I have tried to understand condition variable using below code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>
#include <mutex>
#include <condition_variable>

using namespace std;
std::mutex mu;
std::condition_variable multiple;
bool isLoaded = false;

void func1()
{
    std::unique_lock<std::mutex> unLock(mu);
    multiple.wait(unLock, []() {return isLoaded; });
    for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
    {        
        cout << "This is from thread; " << i << endl;                
    }
}

int main()
{
    std::thread t1(func1);
    std::lock_guard<std::mutex> gaurd(mu);

    cout << std::thread::hardware_concurrency()<< endl;

    for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
    {
        if (i == 50)
        {
            isLoaded = true;
            multiple.notify_one();
            std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::seconds(4));
        }
        cout << "This is from main; " << i << endl;
    }

    t1.join();
    getchar();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Just a note on style: `using namespace std;` says "I don't want to write `std::` everywhere, and I'll take my chances with name collisions". It's generally frowned upon, and since your code fairly scrupulously uses `std::` as appropriate, you can remove it with minimal other changes. (`std::cout` may be the only change needed)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You never release `mu` in main thread. Try something like this:

```
int main()
{
    std::thread t1(func1);

    cout << std::thread::hardware_concurrency()<< endl;

    for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
    {
        if (i == 50)
        {
            {
                std::lock_guard<std::mutex> gaurd(mu);
                isLoaded = true;
            }
            multiple.notify_one();
            std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::seconds(4));
        }
        cout << "This is from main; " << i << endl;
    }

    t1.join();
    getchar();
    return 0;
}
```

In general you need to keep your locks for absolute minimum of time you can.

Comment: Ok I guess I understood the problem. I have taken to cout resource in main and my thread doesn't access to this, So its not able to print. I agree to this. But the in main function if i call notify_one() will my thread func1() will be awakened or not?

Comment: It will be awakened. Then (in your version of code) the thread will find, that mutex `mu` is still held and will be slept again.

Comment: This situation doesn't have any relation to `cout` object, although using it from different threads without synchronization can generate "interesting" results. Problem is that you hold mutex.

Comment: Thank your for your comments, Now it gave me clarity. Thank you both for the help

Comment: @Val_MagicStar If you use mutex then we have to specify lock and explicitly unlock at end of critical section of the code, If you use std::lock_gaurd, it automatically unlocks the mutex when gaurd goes out of scope

Answer (score 3):

You are taking mutex `mu` at start of your program and never let it go, so any other code under this mutex will never be executed.

Instead you should only hold it when you changing shared variables, something like:

```
    {
        std::lock_guard<std::mutex> gaurd(mu);
        isLoaded = true;
        multiple.notify_one();
    }
```